# How to use socket.io in multiple routes in node js

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, notifications, real-time

I want to send real time notifications in my MERN app. And I am using socket.io for it. The thing I am confused with is that where should I initialize my socket.io if I want to use it on multiple routes. And how do I use it.

Every time a certain event happens I want to notify the user through a post route and there are multiple post routes like that. So my question is where should I initialize my socket.io for multiple usage and how should I use it.
Please give me the code for it and make it clear for me.

Currently I am initializing my socket.io after connection of my server with my Database like this

```
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MongoDb_Url)
  .then(() => {
    const io = socket(
      app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server And Database Are Running")),
      {
        cors: {
          origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        },
      }
    );
    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.on("message", async (message) => {
        const messageCreated = await chatModel.create({ ...message });
        socket.emit("createdMessage", messageCreated);
      });
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

Now what should I do ?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again. Edit the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75495665/1318694) with the extra detail required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually achieved it through the `app.set()` method in my app.js file

```
app.set("io",io)
```

and then you can just access that in the request object of your route.

```
console.log(req.app.settings.io)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first set io to be assessable in all file using this:

```
app.set('io', io);
```

And then you can use it in anywhere that has access to app object.

```
const io = app.get('io');
```

For controllers you can make a middleware like below:

```
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    request.io = io;
    next();
});
```